# First line of paragraph is not justified?

Tags: horizontal-alignment

[image]

For some reason, first line is not justified. This is how the code of the image looks like:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,titlepage,twoside,openright,openbib]{report}

\def\lingua{esp}
\def\nome{Name}                     
\def\nomedirectora{Name}      
\def\nomedirectorb{Name}            
\def\titulo{Title} 
\def\mencion{Mention}

\usepackage{estilo_tfg}


\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\bstctlcite{IEEEexample:BSTcontrol}

\chapter{Metodología de segmentación}
\label{chap:segmentation}

\lettrine{E}{n} este capítulo se desglosa la metodología utilizada en la segmentación automática de las imágenes y finalmente se exponen los resultados obtenidos. 

\section{Análisis de histograma}
\label{sec:algorithms}

Previo al desarrollo de los algoritmos empleados es conveniente destacar ciertas características de las imágenes a tratar. En ellas se distinguen tres tonalidades claramente diferenciables. La primera es una tonalidad clara o muy clara que, por lo general, se asocia a la cabeza del cometa. La segunda tonalidad es una intensidad generalmente intermedia, y se asocia a  la cola de los cometas. Finalmente, la tonalidad más oscura pertenece al fondo de la imagen. Esto sucede en términos generales, pues una célula lo suficientemente degradada puede tener prácticamente el mismo nivel de gris en la cabeza que en la cola. Además, las imágenes también pueden presentar ruido u objetos anómalos de todas las tonalidades. En la figura~\ref{fig:cells} se pueden apreciar las distintas tonalidades. Las células 1 y 4 son células sanas con una tonalidad muy clara. Las células 2 y 3 están degradadas, teniendo la cabeza (parte delimitada de color verde) con una tonalidad muy clara, y la cola con una tonalidad intermedia (parte delimitada de color roja). El resto de color oscuro es el fondo. 

\end{document}
```

The package "estilo_tfg" was provided by our university. The filename is "estilo_tfg.sty", and the content is the following:

```
\ProvidesPackage{estilo_tfg}
\typeout{=============== Estilo LaTeX para TFGs GEI FIC ===============}

%%                                   %%
%% Paquetes a incluir por defecto    %%
%%                                   %%

\RequirePackage{xcolor}
\RequirePackage{graphicx}
\RequirePackage[pdfencoding=auto,colorlinks]{hyperref}
\RequirePackage{lettrine}
\RequirePackage{appendix}
\RequirePackage{polyglossia}
\RequirePackage{ifthen}

\ifdefined\lingua
  \message{Estilo TFG: elixiuse como lingua do documento: \lingua}
\else
  \message{Estilo TFG warning: non se elixiu lingua para o documento (fallback: galego)}
  \def\lingua{gal} % fórzase a definición da lingua principal a galego
\fi
\ifthenelse{\equal{\lingua}{gal}}{%
  \message{Estilo TFG: cargando definicións para galego}
  \setdefaultlanguage{galician}
  \setotherlanguage{english}
  \def\tituloagradecementos{Agradecementos}
  \def\palabraschaveprincipal{Palabras chave}
  \def\palabraschavesecundaria{Keywords}
  \def\nomeglosarioacronimos{Relación de Acrónimos}
  \def\nomeglosariotermos{Glosario}
  \newenvironment{segundoresumo}
                 {\begin{english}\centerline{\bfseries \abstractname}\vspace*{0.5cm}}
                 {\end{english}}
  \renewcommand{\appendixpagename}{Apéndices}
  \def\bibconfig{bibliografia/bibconf-gl}
}{%
\ifthenelse{\equal{\lingua}{esp}}{%
  \message{Estilo TFG: cargando definicións para español}
  \setdefaultlanguage{spanish}
  \setotherlanguage{galician}
  \setotherlanguage{english}
  \def\tituloagradecementos{Agradecimientos}
  \def\palabraschaveprincipal{Palabras clave}
  \def\palabraschavesecundaria{Keywords}
  \def\nomeglosarioacronimos{Lista de acrónimos}
  \def\nomeglosariotermos{Glosario}
  \newenvironment{segundoresumo}
                 {\begin{english}\centerline{\bfseries \abstractname}\vspace*{0.5cm}}
                 {\end{english}}
  \renewcommand{\appendixpagename}{Apéndices}
  \gappto\captionsspanish{\renewcommand{\tablename}{Tabla}}
  \gappto\captionsspanish{\renewcommand{\listtablename}{Índice de tablas}}
  \def\bibconfig{bibliografia/bibconf-es}
}
}{%
\ifthenelse{\equal{\lingua}{eng}}{%
  \message{Estilo TFG: cargando definicións para inglés}
  \setdefaultlanguage{english}
  \setotherlanguage{galician}
  \def\tituloagradecementos{Acknowledgements}
  \def\palabraschaveprincipal{Keywords}
  \def\palabraschavesecundaria{Palabras chave}
  \def\nomeglosarioacronimos{List of Acronyms}
  \def\nomeglosariotermos{Glossary}
  \newenvironment{segundoresumo}
                 {\begin{galician}\centerline{\bfseries \abstractname}\vspace*{0.5cm}}
                 {\end{galician}}
  \def\bibconfig{bibliografia/bibconf-en}
}{%
  \message{Estilo TFG warning: non se detectou correctamente a lingua (fallback: galego)}
}}

\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage[hmargin={4cm,2.5cm},tmargin=4cm,bmargin=4cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{libertine}

\usepackage{datetime}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{IEEEtrantools}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[numbers,sort]{natbib}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[nottoc,notlot,notlof,notindex]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{url}

\usepackage{blindtext}

%% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% % definición de comandos               %
%% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\definecolor{udcpink}{RGB}{177,0,114}
\definecolor{udcgray}{RGB}{100,100,100}
\definecolor{ficblue}{RGB}{50,110,118}

\newcommand{\paxinaenbranco}{\mbox{}\thispagestyle{empty}\clearpage}
\newcommand{\dedicatoria}[1]{\thispagestyle{empty}\mbox{}\vfill\hfill\emph{#1}\vfill}
\newenvironment{agradecementos}
               {\thispagestyle{empty}
                 \vspace*{175pt}
                 \subsubsection*{\centering \tituloagradecementos}}
               {\paxinaenbranco}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% opcións titlesec                     %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand{\bigrule}{{\color{udcpink}\titlerule[0.5mm]}}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]%
{\bfseries\Huge}%
{\filleft\Large\chaptertitlename \Large{} \thechapter}%
{0mm}{\filleft}[\vspace{0.5cm} \bigrule]

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% opcións fancyhdr                     %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[LO]{{\small\leftmark}}
\fancyhead[RE]{{\small\nouppercase{\textsl{\rightmark}}}}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[CE,CO]{\thepage}
\setlength{\headheight}{14pt}

\usepackage{everypage}
\makeatletter
\AddEverypageHook{%
  \ifthenelse{\(\value{page}>80\) \AND \(\NOT \equal{\@chapapp}{\appendixname}\)}
             {\message{Estilo TFG warning: sobrepasado o límite de 80 páxinas antes dos apéndices!}
              \fancyfoot[CE,CO]{\color{red} \hrulefill PÁXINA EXTRA \hrulefill \thepage{} \hrulefill PÁXINA EXTRA \hrulefill}}
             {\fancyfoot[CE,CO]{\thepage}}
}
\makeatother

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% opcións setspace                     %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\onehalfspacing

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% opcións hyperref                     %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\hypersetup{
 colorlinks=true,
 linkcolor=ficblue,
 filecolor=ficblue,      
 urlcolor=ficblue,
 citecolor=ficblue
}
\hypersetup{pdfauthor={\nome},
            pdftitle={\titulo}
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% opcións datetime                     %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newdateformat{datasimple}{\begin{galician}\monthname[\THEMONTH] de \THEYEAR\end{galician}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% opcións listings                     %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\lstset{
  basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize, % estilo da fonte para entornos de código
  breakatwhitespace=true,            % pártense as liñas só polos espazos en branco
  breaklines=true,                   % pártense as liñas automaticamente
  captionpos=b,                      % a lenda vai debaixo
  commentstyle=\color{udcgray},      % os comentarios van en gris
  frame=single,                      % o código leva un cadro arredor
  keepspaces=true,                   % respéctanse os espazos no código LaTeX
  keywordstyle=\color{ficblue},      % as palabras chave da linguaxe van en azul
  linewidth=0.95\textwidth,          % anchura do entorno de código
  numbers=left,                      % numéranse as liñas á esquerda
  numbersep=5pt,                     % separación da numeración das liñas
  numberstyle=\tiny\color{udcgray},  % estilo da numeración
  rulecolor=\color{black},           % color do cadro arredor do código
  showspaces=false,                  % non se mostran os espazos
  showstringspaces=false,            % non se mostran os espazos nas cadeas de texto
  showtabs=false,                    % non se mostran os tabuladores
  stepnumber=1,                      % a numeración de liñas vai de dúas en dúas
  stringstyle=\color{udcpink},       % as cadeas de texto literais aparecen en rosado
  tabsize=2,                         % os tabuladores equivalen a dous espazos
  xleftmargin=0.05\textwidth         % identación extra desde a marxe esquerda
}

\endinput
```

Comment: Could you please make your example code compilable  (See: [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)) so others can reproduce the issue you describe?

Comment: In particular, in order to have a chance to come up with a meaningful diagnosis, it's essential to know which document class is employed and which package are loaded (and with which options).

Comment: Please make your code fragment compilable. Missed are your document  preamble, `begin{document}`, `\end{document}`. Please test your MWE (Minimal Working Example, a small complete document which reproduce your problem) before you upload here.

Comment: I'm not at my pc, but you need `\usepackage[T1] {fontenc} ` and `babel` correctly configured to be able to hyphenate words with non-ascii chars...

Comment: I've edited the question with compilable code.

Comment: Do you have any messages in the log-file concerning hyphenation patterns or overfull hboxes? Can you post these messages?

Comment: @Rmano Now that we have the local package we know that it is being compiled with XeLaTeX (since `polyglossia` is loaded) so it is inappropriate to load `fontenc` with the `[T1]` encoding.

Comment: if the log file is the ".log", it is empty. However, on the compiling terminal there are warnings like this one:

Package polyglossia Warning: No hyphenation patterns were loaded for `Spanish'
(polyglossia)                I will use \language=\l@nohyphenation instead on i
nput line 8.


Package polyglossia Warning: \setlocalhyphenmin useless for unhyphenated langua
ge spanish on input line 8.

Comment: Overfull \hbox (17.38513pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 90--91.
 0 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191

Comment: If that's the warning, it's likely that your TeX distribution isn't complete. Are you on Linux? See [No hyphenation patterns were loaded for the language](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/1972)